# Maven dependency imported

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have several projects set up with maven. I use version 1.5 of an api, before this version 1.4 was used. Some project still use this version but they should not. All my info about which projects use it are in the .iml (idea project files). I can't find version 1.4 mentioned in any pom.xml.If i change the .iml file/project settings, on maven update the files are overwritten and still on maven updated version 1.4 is retrieved. Is there a way to find out what project and how this happens?

Comment: Can't you grep for `<version>1.4</version>`? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: I can grep for version 1.4 and the only place i can find it is the .iml idea files. In the pom.xml files a ${api.version} are used except for the main pom where this value is defined like <api.version>1.5</api.version>

Comment: Can you provide your .iml and the relevant part of your pom.xml? Thks

Comment: Is this a multi module project? Do they share a common parent? Do you use dependency management blocks?

Comment: When you run `mvn dependency:tree` on your project, you will see how your dependencies are resolved.